# Select soft deleted record when using left join nestjs

Tags: mysql, nestjs, typeorm

I have an **order** table with relation **address**

```js
@Entity('orders')
export class Order {
  ...
  @ManyToOne(() => Address, (address) => address.orders)
  address: Address;
  ...
}
```

```js
@Entity('addresses')
export class Address {
  ...
  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt?: Date;
  ...
}
```

**address** table using soft-deleted, If I using query below I can't get soft-deleted **address** record

```js
const query = this.createQueryBuilder('order')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('order.address', 'address');
```

I want to get all **order** with **address** either soft-deleted or not. Have any query for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following syntax:

```js
const query = this.createQueryBuilder('order')
  .withDeleted()
  .leftJoinAndSelect('order.address', 'address')
  .where('order.deletedAt is NULL')
```

Make sure to add `.withDeleted` before your join, else the deleted `Address` entities will not be returned. If `order` can be soft deleted as well, make sure to explicitly select the non-deleted entities as well to exclude it from the `withDeleted` condition.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! I have already tried `.withDeleted` after `leftJoinAndSelect` and return null at `Address`...